# SQL multiple rows as columns with out using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

I have 3 tables

- `questions (q_id, q_text)`
- `answers (a_id, a_text, q_id)`
- `correct_answers (q_id, a_id)`

answers table can have minimum of 1 and maximum of 4 values for each question

I need a pure SQL query (joins or sub query) to have following table as result

```
result (q_id, q_text, option1, option2, option3, option4, correct)
```

`option1`, `option2`, `option3`, `option4` all belong to answers tables and can be `null`, `correct` belong to `correct_answers` table

Questions:

```
q_id  q_text
2     Capital of Pakistan is
3     Karachi is in africa
5     New dehli is _____ of india
```

Answers:

```
a_id  a_text     q_id
1     Lahore     2
2     Islamabad  2
3     Karachi    2
4     Quetta     2
5     True       3
6     False      3
7     Capital    5
```

Correct_answer:

```
q_id  a_id
2     2
3     6
5     7
```

result of query:

```
q_id  q_text                       option_1   option_2   option_3  option_4 correct
2     Capital of Pakistan is       Lahore     Islamabad  Karachi   Quetta   Islamabad
3     Karachi is in africa         True       False      null      null     False
5     New dehli is _____ of india  Capital    Null       Null      Null     Capital
```

Comment: What database engine are you using? I've read, that you need "pure SQL" solution, so you want something universal, but there are few SQL dialects - most popular are SQL-92, SQL-99.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works with ORACLE, MySQL, MS SQL Server and PostgreSQL

```
SELECT q_id, 
       q_text,
       (SELECT a_text
          FROM answers a1
         WHERE a1.q_id = q1.q_id
           AND (SELECT count(*) FROM answers a2 WHERE a1.q_id = a2.q_id AND a2.a_id < a1.a_id) = 0) as option1,
       (SELECT a_text
          FROM answers a1
         WHERE a1.q_id = q1.q_id
           AND (SELECT count(*) FROM answers a2 WHERE a1.q_id = a2.q_id AND a2.a_id < a1.a_id) = 1) as option2,
       (SELECT a_text
          FROM answers a1
         WHERE a1.q_id = q1.q_id
           AND (SELECT count(*) FROM answers a2 WHERE a1.q_id = a2.q_id AND a2.a_id < a1.a_id) = 2) as option3,
       (SELECT a_text 
          FROM answers a1
         WHERE a1.q_id = q1.q_id
           AND (SELECT count(*) FROM answers a2 WHERE a1.q_id = a2.q_id AND a2.a_id < a1.a_id) = 3) as option4,
       (SELECT a_text
          FROM answers a1
         WHERE a1.a_id = (select a_id from correct_answers c1 where c1.q_id = q1.q_id)) as correct
  FROM questions q1;
```

Cheers!

Comment: Triangle-join aggregates in subqueries within subqueries. Clever and technically correct, but potentially a performance nightmare if the number of rows gets even moderately high.

Comment: I agree - this is probably *not* clever if you need a good performance ;)

Comment: Checkout Fiddle above; note that I used table `correct_answers` instead of `Correct_answer`; no further need to tweek - this worked with all of menitioned databases above.

Answer (score 6):

You did not specify what RDBMS but since you said PL/SQL I am guessing Oracle.

Depending on your version you should be able to use the following to *pivot* the data in most database products:

```
select q_id,
  q_text,
  max(case when rn = 1 then answer end) Option1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then answer end) Option2,
  max(case when rn = 3 then answer end) Option3,
  max(case when rn = 4 then answer end) Option4,
  CorrectAnswer
from
(
  select q.q_id,
    q.q_text,
    a1.a_text Answer,
    a2.a_text CorrectAnswer,
    row_number() over(partition by q.q_id order by a1.a_id) rn
  from questions q
  left join answers a1
    on q.q_id = a1.q_id
  left join Correct_answer ca
    on q.q_id = ca.q_id
  left join answers a2
    on ca.a_id = a2.a_id
)
group by q_id, q_text, CorrectAnswer
order by q_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d104d/13).

If you are using Oracle 11g+, then you can use the `PIVOT` function:

```
select q_id,
  q_text,
  Option1, Option2, Option3, Option4,
  CorrectAnswer
from
(
  select q.q_id,
    q.q_text,
    a1.a_text Answer,
    a2.a_text CorrectAnswer,
    row_number() over(partition by q.q_id order by a1.a_id) rn
  from questions q
  left join answers a1
    on q.q_id = a1.q_id
  left join Correct_answer ca
    on q.q_id = ca.q_id
  left join answers a2
    on ca.a_id = a2.a_id
)
pivot
(
  max(answer)
  for rn in ('1' as Option1, '2' as Option2, 
             '3' as Option3, '4' as Option4)
) piv
order by q_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d104d/18)

Comment: +1 for SQL Fiddle. Very cool! That said, as I mentioned in my answer, I wouldn't advocate ordering by the surrogate key. Quizzes and tests generally have their answers in a specific order that should be managed explicitly.

Comment: PL/SQL is supported in many databases (even in MySQL), and you assumed he is using probably most complicated RDBMS ever made which supports almost everything... :)

Comment: @Kamil you are correct, I am making that assumption...the OP should really specify what database they are using.  If they are using MySQL, the answer can be altered for that database.

Comment: @Kamil: not really, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL; MsSQL uses "T-SQL"; PostreSQL uses "PL/pgSQL"; MySQL calls it simply "Stored procedures" as far as I know :)

Comment: @André thanks. I thought PL/SQL is procedural SQL supported in many RDBMS, and that all SQL with loops, conditions, and begin-end blocks are called PL/SQL, because of procedural orientation.

Answer (score -1):

I would start by adding a `Position` column to the `Answers` table, with a unique constraint over `(q_id, Position)` and a domain constraint `Position > 0 AND Position <= 4`. You might want a `Position` column anyway; it's generally better to explicitly order your rows when they have a natural order instead of trying to order them by their surrogate keys or just discarding the ordering information altogether.

That sets you up to query the database more less like this:

```
SELECT
        q.qid, q.q_text,
        a1.a_text AS option1, a2.a_text AS option2,
        a3.a_text AS option3, a4.a_text AS option4,
        ca.a_text AS correct
    FROM
        Questions q
        LEFT JOIN Answers a1 ON a1.q_id = q.q_id AND a1.Position = 1
        LEFT JOIN Answers a2 ON a2.q_id = q.q_id AND a2.Position = 2
        LEFT JOIN Answers a3 ON a3.q_id = q.q_id AND a3.Position = 3
        LEFT JOIN Answers a4 ON a4.q_id = q.q_id AND a4.Position = 4
        JOIN Correct_answer qca ON ca.q_id = q.q_id
        JOIN Anwsers ca ON ca.a_id = qca.a_id
```

You can get away with this because you have a fixed number of possible answers; a more general solution might require dynamic SQL or application-layer code to pivot the result set.

Comment: First sentence of my answer: "I would start by adding a Position column to the Answers table." I'm suggesting a change to the schema for a couple of reasons, and I outline those reasons in my first paragraph.

Comment: Ok, I see your point; but still I think it's far away from the question cause you changed the pre-requisites.

Comment: It's common on SO and elsewhere to recommend a schema change if the query being requested is cumbersome with the given schema. I would appreciate if you consider revoking your down-vote now that I've explained myself. Also, by deleting your original comment, you've  stripped the subsequent comments of useful context.

Comment: In my opinion your answer is not as helpful, because you need some DDL changes and this is not absolutely necessary as bluefeet showed. Even worse: you have to adapt your constraint in case you want to add one or more answers. Of course there are many options to change the initial setup - but does it still answer the question?

Comment: I would argue that the original schema is insufficient. Surrogate keys should have no meaning, and bluefeet assigned meaning to them by making the order of the keys imply the order of the questions. If those surrogate keys are automatically generated by the database, changing the order of the answers becomes a lot more difficult, especially if there are other tables using the `Answers.a_id` column. If the order of the questions matters (which is likely), the original schema is wrong; unless the poster says, "This is a legacy schema that I cannot change," I will always point out a bad design.

Comment: The salient point is that SO isn't a forum where users help trouble other users' specific problems. It's a Q&A site where answers should be useful for posterity. I made no unreasonable assumptions about the original post or about situations that future readers might find themselves in. That fact that my answer is only conditional useful doesn't make it useless.

Comment: schema is just small part of main schema, actually total DB have 83 tables. this schema was related to this query only. but there is also a lot of data in it so modifying it will be a big trouble